# How to connect to a SQL Server from an m1 chip macbook

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssms, azure-data-studio

I am working on a project with a friend and he has deployed a SQL Server database. He uses a PC and can access the database using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).

However I have a Macbook with an M1 chip and so I cannot use SSMS and need to figure out which SQL Server application I want.

It seems like the way to go is Microsoft Azure Data Studio. I cannot figure out how to connect properly, I have looked at several solutions posted online which all say to download docker, download the latest SQL Server image, use SQL edge, run SQL Server in a container and then open Azure and connect.

One caveat is that all these tutorials end with creating a SQL Server on the local host rather than connecting to an existing one.

In Azure, after entering server id, username and password, there is a green dot on the label of the DB on the left drop down menu, indicating that the connection to the DB was successful. However whenever I try to view the DB's from the drop down it loads and then errors:

> Object Explorer task didn't complete within 45 seconds

and I cannot run any basic queries either.

At this point I don't care what IDE I use as long as it works. Any advice is much appreciated. It seems like this task should be super easy but has given me such a hard time and we cannot continue working on the project until I get access.

Anyways, thanks again in advance! and lmk if there's any other info I should provide.

Tried using docker with Azure Data Studio and my results were the same as when I only used Azure.

Comment: Where is the SQL database hosted? On your friend's PC? Azure?

Comment: On MacOS with M1, use homebrew to install `dbeaver` ($ brew install --cask dbeaver-community), then create a SQL Server connection using JDBC.

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to use [Azure Data Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/download-azure-data-studio?view=sql-server-ver16).

You don't need Docker at all to meet your goals. Those tutorials were in regards to running your own SQL Server instance on a Mac. You're trying to connect to an existing instance.

As mentioned in the comments, where is the existing SQL Server instance located?...is it on a server that's part of a domain. Is your Mac part of that same domain? It sounds like you're getting some kind of timeout issue or some sort of authentication issue. So this is more of an infrastructure question.

Once connected to the SQL Server instance in Azure Data Studio, what happens if you just open a blank worksheet and run the query `SELECT @@SERVERNAME`?